# Reference for Affine Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request

I recently started reading Arnold's **Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics** (Second Edition). On pg. 4 Arnold writes:

> *Affine $n$-dimensional space* $A^n$ is distinguished from $\mathbb R^n$ in that there is "no fixed origin". The group $\mathbb R^n$ acts on $A^n$ as the *group of parallel displacements*:
>   $$a\rightarrow a+\mathbf b, \quad a\in A^n, \mathbf b\in \mathbb R^n, a+\mathbf b\in A^n$$

This is the way Arnold defines an affine space. I really do not understand what he is trying to say here. I checked the wikipedia article on affine space and it made much more sense to me: An affine space A is a set on which a vector space acts transitively and freely.

I'd like to learn more about affine spaces in the same spirit as in the wikipedia article. Can somebody tell me from what book (or online notes) can I learn about affine spaces in some detail from a modern algebraic point of view?

Thank you.

Comment: Just from other posts: [here's something](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469059/affine-space-an-and-definition-of-difference?rq=1) and [here's a book maybe](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1441928065/?tag=stackoverfl08-20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the treatment in [Audin's *Geometry*](http://amzn.com/3540434984). There are probably other equivalent books but I've used it both as a student and as a teacher, and I really like it.